# How do I play a random sound on button-press in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, buttonclick

I want to add a button on my app. I want to: When I click the button, random sound play. I typed this codes but when I ran the project emulator was closing

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //MediaPlayer
    MediaPlayer mp;
    ImageButton soundbutton;

    //Sounds
    int[] sounds={R.raw.s1, R.raw.s2, R.raw.s3, R.raw.s4, R.raw.s5, R.raw.s6, R.raw.s7, R.raw.s8, R.raw.s9, R.raw.s10};
    Random r = new Random();
    int Low = 0;
    int High = 10;
    int rndm = r.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //MediaPlayer
        soundbutton = (ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.randomsoundbutton89);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),sounds[rndm]);
        soundbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                        mp.stop();
                        mp.release();
                        rndm = r.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;
                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),sounds[rndm]);
                    }
                    mp.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your output logs?

Comment: No there aren't